# Confusion with docker bind and type parameters

Tags: docker-compose

I have below two volumes in my docker compose file.
I need to confirm if I am using the correct type or not. I am confuse what is the difference between "type" and "o".
Can anyone please guide?

```
volumes:
  var-run-ip111:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: /var/run/ip360
      o: bind
  var-run-postgresql:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "ext4"
      device: /var/run/postgresql
      o: bind
```

Comment: I have seen many references where they have used type: "nfs" or type: "none".
Not sure what would be the correct one.

Comment: type is the mount type and o is optional like read:write or readonly ....

[link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver_opts)

Comment: So mount type can be ext4?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/